# How do I update a node's file field from within a module?

Tags: 7, files

I have a file: `/tmp/new.zip` and I have a node, `$node`, that has a file field, `field_ios_file`. Currently, `old.zip` is the file saved in to the `field_ios_file` field. I'd like to put `/tmp/new.zip` there.

What I have now:

```
$file = file_uri_to_object('/tmp/new.zip');                                                                                
print_r($node->field_ios_file);
$node->field_ios_file['und'][0] = $file ;
print_r($node->field_ios_file);
node_save($node);
```

the `node_save()` fails here because `$node->field_ios_file['und'][0]` should be an array, not an object. I would imagine there is a function that looks something like `field_update($node, $my_field, $data)`, but I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file field type has a `fid` column (file ID); you just need to save the file so an ID is populated, and add it to the node like this:

```
$file = file_uri_to_object('/tmp/new.zip');  
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT; 
file_save($file);

$node->field_ios_file[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'] = $file->fid;
node_save($node);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is that true regardless of private / public types of file fields?